# SelectMethod of asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Can anyone tell me when is the SelectMethod called. Also if I want to  invoke it at certain point, is it possible?

Comment: Share the code that you have tried or write if you have faced any issue using it?

Comment: I got the solution. We can use gridview.DataBind() to invoke the SelectMethod as many number of times as we want.